# Q, amd and concatenation with grunt

Tags: gruntjs, amd, q, grunt-contrib-concat

I'm using `AMD`-like function in my project, but all js files are concatenated into one (with `grunt-contrib-concat`).
I want Q to be concatenated as well. The problem is I can't declare Q as dependency in my other modules, cause it [declares](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/q.js#L47) itself as anonymous one.

```
define('mymodule', ['q'], function (Promise) {
    return Promise;
});
```

What are possible solutions? I actually need only files to be concatenated, AMD may be changed to e.g. any other loader.

Comment: Perhaps file an issue against Q suggesting how it would need to be revised to support your use-case. In v2 (there is a branch), Q is in CommonJS only format and the AMD version is built and published to S3 for each commit. Perhaps the AMD form can be made more suitable for your case.

Comment: Thanks, Kris. I suggest, I'll switch to `CommonJS` for now and will create an issue.